# Calculate the length of AC

Tags: geometry, triangles

The diameter $AB$ of the circle is $10\,\text{cm}$. The length of $BC$ is $6\,\text{cm}$. Calculate the length of $AC$.

[image]

---

I'm doing a mock exam and I'm not sure how to work out the length of $AC$. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pythagorean Theorem applies: the right angle is $\angle ACB$, by [Thales Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem). So the hypotenuse is $AB = 10$.

$$\begin{align} |AB|^2 & = |AC|^2 + |BC|^2 \\ \\ \iff |AC|^2 & = |AB|^2 - |BC|^2 \\ \\ \iff |AC| & = \sqrt{10^2 - 6^2} = \sqrt{64} = 8\end{align}$$

Comment: aaah ok... oopsy I feel so dumb now, thanks.

Comment: Look at the equation carefully: $10^2 = |BC|^2 + 6^2$

Comment: yep, I understand now. 10 squared, 6 squared, take 6 squared of 10 sqaured and you get 64 which when you square root equals 8 and yes... and i already know how you awfully want to get reputation lol.

Comment: You should add that it is a right triangle due to Thales' theorem.

Comment: Exactly, Honky! ;-)

Comment: Added a link, @Ramchandra

Comment: @amWhy: Links and all +1